# Weird syntax in JavaScript example: `var { variable } = value`

Tags: javascript, syntax

Does anyone know what this syntax means in JavaScript?

```
var { variable } = value;
```

I found it in some code examples and I've never seen this before. Is this JavaScript 6? I tried googling `variable syntax` and `es6` but no examples came up with this syntax.

Here's the full example:

```
var { Tab } = require('app-dev-kit/tab');
var tab = Tab({ properties });
```

Weirdest part is if I drop parens from `{ Tab }` then it doesn't work (it says Tab is not a function in that case):

```
var Tab = require('app-dev-kit/tab');
var tab = Tab({ properties });
```

This doesn't work: `Error: Tab is not a function`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ES6 feature known as [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that works for arrays (array destructuring) and objects (object destructuring)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to extract data from arrays or objects using a
>   syntax that mirrors the construction of array and object literals.

Say you have a function

```
function foo() {
    return { bar: 1, baz: 2 };
}
```

And you want to assign the properties of that functions returned value to local variables. Traditionally, you would do something like

```
var f = foo();
var bar = f.bar; 
var baz = f.baz;
console.log(bar); // 1
console.log(baz); // 2
```

With destructuring assignment, you can do this

```
var {bar, baz} = foo();
console.log(bar); // 1
console.log(baz); // 2
```

Comment: Very confusing. This is something new. Any ideas what what does `require('app-dev-kit/tab')` does return in this case? And why is it designed this way? I'm used to regular `var thing = require('thing')`.

Comment: `console.log()` it and see. In that case it presumably returns an object with at least one property `Tab`. "And why is it designed this way?" --- ask the library developer. "I'm used to regular" - okay.

Comment: It actually works with any object that is iterable, not just arrays.